# Implementing TestNg suite programmatically and executing it via maven surefire

Tags: java, unit-testing, testng, maven-surefire-plugin

How to implement TestNG test suite using java instead of testng.xml. i follow following procedure but i cannot run it with the maven suefire plug in.

Please help

```
  TestNG testNG = new TestNG();
    List<XmlClass> classList =new ArrayList<XmlClass>();
    List<XmlTest> testList = new ArrayList<XmlTest>();
    List<XmlSuite> suiteList= new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
    List<String> suiteNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    XmlTest xmlTest= new XmlTest();
    XmlSuite suite = new XmlSuite();
    XmlClass xmlClass = new XmlClass();
    xmlClass.setClass(bpsTestNg.class);
    classList.add(xmlClass);
    xmlTest.setClasses(classList);
    testList.add(xmlTest);
   suite.setTests(testList);
    suiteList.add(suite);
    suite.setName("sampleSuite1");
    suiteNameList.add("sampleSuite1")  ;
    suite.toXml();
    IConfiguration iConfiguration = null;
    SuiteRunner suiteRunner= new SuiteRunner(iConfiguration,suite,".");
    suiteRunner.run();
```

Thank You,
Dharshana.

Comment: Frankly not sure why you are even doing it like this (just annotate your classes), but fwiw, this is what the docs say: http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically

Comment: I just use it with @BeforeSuite annotation. Why i need this is im using listeners with surefire. At start of every suite im triggering a listener and performing a task. but with directly providing suite xml to surefire triggers errors. Thats why i tried to create a suite by code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi i resolved this issue please refer the code below

```
 @BeforeSuite
 public static void TestSuite() {
    TestNG testNG = new TestNG();

    List<Class> listnerClasses = new ArrayList<Class>();
    List<String> suiteNameList = new ArrayList<String>();
    Class[] classList = new Class[]{
            ManagementClient.class,
            ProcessManagementClient.class,
            DeployClient.class,
            RedeployClient.class};
    listnerClasses.add(org.wso2.platform.test.core.PlatformTestManager.class);
    listnerClasses.add(org.wso2.platform.test.core.PlatformSuiteManager.class);        
    testNG.setDefaultSuiteName("suite");
    testNG.setListenerClasses(listnerClasses);
    testNG.setTestClasses(classList);
    testNG.run();
}
```

Thank You all for your help :)

EDIT: Improved formatting ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you're using the API, your main class is no longer a TestNG test class, just a regular Java class, so it's not surprising that Surefire no longer sees it as a test.

Comment: Hi Beust.Im running the class with surefire using @BeforeSuite annotation. my case is i have complex test structure where im using a suite listener and perform a task. I even cannnot use all suite xmls in my root pom. It is a reason why i trying to create suite by code. So i can include it in the surefire with parameter.