# Dynamic Test Suites Using TestNG

Tags: unit-testing, testng

I want to write Java code that dynamically creates multiple TestNG test suite from a directory full of files. Each file corresponds to a test suite that contains tests based upon the contents of the file. The key being that I need to do specific setup and tear down for each suite.

I know that I can use the Factory annotation to dynamically build a test from a single file. For example:

```
public class TestFactory {
    @Factory
    public Object[] createTestFromFile() throws Exception {
        ArrayList<MyTest> tests = new ArrayList<MyTest>();

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("test1.txt"));
        String testData;
        while ((testData = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            tests.add(new MyTest(testData));
        }

        return tests.toArray();
    }
}

public class MyTest {
    private String testData;

    public MyTest(String testData) {
        this.testData = testData;
    }

    @Test
    public void runTest() {
        assertTrue(testData.equals(testData));
    }

}
```

But how do I read multiple files and create a separate test suite for each file, each with a different suite specific setup/teardown?

Answer (score 4):

Probably this can help : [Running TestNG programmatically](http://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#running-testng-programmatically)  You can create dynamic suites using the XMLSuite class, probably set your file name as a parameter in the suite and your setup/teardown as listeners.

Comment: Building my own test suites seems like the approach I was hoping for, but if I understand correctly I would have to initiate the execution of the suites directly. For example: (new TestNG(add suites)).run(); This would make it difficult to run the tests from enviornments like Gradle or Intellij without writing even more framework code. At that point I am starting to wonder why I am using TestNG.

Comment: I guess I do not get the issue since m not familiar with gradle. But as far as invocation is concerned, you just need to add your suites to your testng instance in your main method and invoke it. egList<XmlSuite> suites = new ArrayList<XmlSuite>();
suites.add(suite);
TestNG tng = new TestNG();
tng.setXmlSuites(suites);
tng.run();

Comment: The problem is that I don't have a main method. I am relying on my execution framework to provide that. For example if I am using Intellij to run tests, then I am using Intellij's "main method" initiated by right clicking "run tests" in the IDE. After look at this problem I am pretty convinced that TestNG cannot build a complex suite of tests. This was so easy in JUnit3. I don't get why the used case was dropped.

Comment: Can you [use @BeforeSuite](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9003754/implementing-testng-suite-programmatically-and-executing-it-via-maven-surefire)?